# Copy MinGW w64 runtime dlls to the target directory under Windows using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am trying to use CLion + MinGW to develop an application on Windows.

The program can be compiled and run normally, but when I enter the `cmake-build-debug` folder to run the program alone, the program reports an error that the runtime dynamic library is missing.

When I manually copied these dll files from the `mingw/bin` folder, the program can run normally.

Files：
`libatomic-1.dll`, `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll`,  `libgomp-1.dll`, `libssp-0.dll`, `libstdc++-6.dll`, `libwinpthread-1.dll`

However, it is very troublesome to manually copy these files every time. I would like to ask if there is any way to automatically copy these files

I know there are `add_custom_command` statements that can help me copy files, but I can't get the path to those DLLs

Comment: When you say you "can't get the path to those DLLs" what do you mean? That you don't know where those DLLs are? If you know where the DLLs are and you want to copy them to the build directory that is straight forward in CMake. I will write a comment with another answer's link.

Comment: The list of dlls and their paths can be parsed from the output of `ntldd -R your_program.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the location of the DLLs you want to copy over you can use the CMake `file` function. If the DLLs happen to be where the C++ compiler is located you can use this example to locate the `libatomic-1.dll` .

```
file( COPY  "${PATH_TO_YOUR_DLL}/libatomic-1.dll" DESTINATION "${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/" )
```

This will copy the file `libatomic-1.dll` to the directory specified by `${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/`

And it will save you from performing this task manually.

If you're unsure where the file will be and want to search for it, then the CMake function `find_path` can search a series of directories for you and return a file's path.

Comment: I was wondering if there is any way for CMake to get the path to the compiler, because these dll files are also in the same path. Although I can specify these paths manually but I want to make it a bit smarter

Comment: @GhostGloomy `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`